# JSP Error Postgres connection

Tags: postgresql, jsp

I am trying to establish a connection between JSP and Postgres. Unfortunately I only see the table with its columnms, the columnms are not filled. How can I put data into the columns?

My code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"
import="java.sql.* "%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Films Example: JSP</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

  <div>
    <h1>Filmworld</h1>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>imdbID</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>year</td>
            <td>rating</td>
            <td>votes</td>
            <td>runtime</td>
            <td>actors</td>
            <td>genres</td>
            <td>directors</td>
        </tr>

        <%
            try {
                String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/movie";
                String username = "postgres";
                String password = "cemcan";
                String myDataField = null;
                String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM movie";
                Connection myConnection = null;
                PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
                ResultSet myResultSet = null;
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                myPreparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
                myResultSet = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
                out.println("<table border=1>");
                while (myResultSet.next()) {
                    String imdbID = myResultSet.getString("imdbID");
                    String name = myResultSet.getString("name");
                    int year = myResultSet.getInt("year");
                    double rating = myResultSet.getDouble("rating");
                    int votes = myResultSet.getInt("votes");
                    int runtime = myResultSet.getInt("runtime");
                    String directors = myResultSet.getString("directors");
                    out.println("<tr><td>" + imdbID + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + year + "</td><td>" + rating
                            + "</td><td>" + votes + "</td> <td>" + runtime + "</td> <td>" + directors + "</td> </tr>");
                }
                out.println("</table>");

                myConnection.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                out.print("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                out.print("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                out.print("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            }
        %>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did you put your jdbc driver?

Comment: @PaulNgom: I editey my question, please have a second look.

Comment: you have removed the most important: the error message

Comment: @PaulNgorn: There is no error message anymore, I did it. But my rows are empty. There are just the columns shown. How can I fill my columns with datas from my database created in postgresql?

Comment: can you put an out statement just before String imdbID = myResultSet.getString("imdbID"); to be sure that the resultSet has some rows? you can update the question with the result of what you see in the jsp.

Comment: please check your server logs for any error

Answer (score 0):

your code has at least two problems:

1. if you don't have the jdbc driver in the classpath the error goes
   into the application server output since you have a line with
   `e.printStackTrace();`. you can check if this is the case because in
   the html generated by jsp you did not see the html `<table
   border=1>`
2. the html is not correct you are putting a table element just after
   a .. element. the elements taken ffrom the db do not need
   an extra tables, thar are already rows. Using a `tbody` is more
   appropriate

I see that this is an example and it's ok for learning, but in "production code" put the login on the server side (servlet, framework controller, etc) and use at least <%=... %> in jsp instead of out, it helps to separate page markup to program variables